# No images are being displayed after migrating drupal website from server to local host

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, drupal-7, xampp

I'm trying to replicate drupal website in my localhost. I have copied all the files from public_html folder and mysql database. I have also updated my database details in settings.php file and deleted all contents of .htaccess file under site folder. But still I'm not able to crack down. Please suggest some solution.

N.B: Also tried refreshing the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please check your network information with your debug window of the
>   browser. then you can identify loading failed resources. so you can
>   troubleshoot your self.

**See the network resources information with google chrome.**

Goto Menu -> More Tools -> Developer Tools, Then click `Network` tab. Refresh the page again. Then your resources will be listed as follows.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I found that, it is pointing to incorrect location i.e.  "/drupal7//sites/default/files/pigasus_1.png". But I checked everywhere and I haven't mentioned such path. Could you suggest where I can find this path in Drupal

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure your `base_url` is defined and all thr content are copyed successfully.

1. Setup a test-site database with phpMyAdmin
2. Change `settings.php` (or includes/conf.php) in your backed-up Drupal files.
3. Upload the backed-up Drupal files to a test-site folder on your server
4. Check if your test site works.
5. Get ready for the basic steps.

[How to copy live site to local server](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade/copying-your-live-site-via-GUI)

Comment: I did all this but unable to retrieve images and themes.